# Give an appropriate region on which the function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

$F(z)=\log(z^4+4i)$

Here is what I did,

Let $z=re^{i\theta} \Rightarrow z^4 =r^4e^{i4\theta}=-4i \Rightarrow r^4=4, \theta=\frac{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi k}{4}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Now $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$\ {$z=re^{i\theta}:r>(4)^{\frac{1}{4}},\theta=\frac{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi k}{4}$} for $k=0,1,2,3$.

My branch cut would be the negative imaginary axis.

Comment: Indeed, F is analytic on the region where $r<4^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $\theta \in [-\pi /8 + \pi k/2, 3\pi /8 + \pi k /2)$.